# Check if user has auto-correction enabled iOS

Tags: ios, autocomplete, uitextview

I have a UITextView which has other views right at the bottom of it. I need to move the content of the text view up when auto-correction is enabled, so that the other views don't cover the little auto-correction window. However, if the pop-up windows never appears, it looks pointless to move the view up. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

You can check it by :

***Swift 2.2***

```
if textField.autocorrectionType == .Yes {
 //do some stuff when auto correction is enabled
}
```

UITextField has a property autocorrectionType that is related with UITextAutoCorrectionType enum. AppleDocumentation about it:

> //
>   // UITextAutocorrectionType
>   //
>   // Controls keyboard autocorrection behavior for a text widget.
>   // Note: Some input methods do not support inline autocorrection, and 
>   // instead use a conversion and/or candidate selection methodology. In such
>   // cases, these values are ignored by the keyboard/input method implementation.
>   //

Comment: This will only tell me the autocorrectionType of the current textfield. It does not work when type is set to default.

Comment: What do you mean by 'it does not work when type is set to default'?

Comment: I mean that, if I set it to default, it will decide whether to use or not use auto-correct based on the user's global setting

Comment: Ok, I understand. I am wondering if condition like `autocorrectionType == .Yes || .Default` will work properly?